Show specific payment option dynamically based on billing email or phone in Woocommerce checkout
I'm building a plugin that will hide a specific payment method based on the email address or phone number typed in the checkout form by the customer.
So at first I used this JS code to catch the onChange of those two fields:
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('form.woocommerce-checkout').length) {
        $('#billing_phone_field, #billing_email_field').on('change', function () {
            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    }
});

Then, I used the hook that's appropriate for manipulating the payment methods array, that is woocommerce_available_payment_gateways in the following way:
public function update_payment_methods_based_on_user_input( $available_gateways ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;

    $wp_session = isset( WC()->session ) && WC()->session->has_session() ? WC()->session : null;

    if ( is_a( $wp_session, 'WC_Session_Handler' ) ) {
        $cust_session = $wp_session->get( 'customer' );

        file_put_contents( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/cust_session.txt', print_r( $cust_session, true ) );
    }

    return $available_gateways;

}

What I was hoping with this was to catch the email address and phone number in the cust_session.txt file, to first check that they exist in the session... But they don't as both email and phone array values are empty.
Am I doing something wrong? How am I supposed to get those two fields if not through the session?

Note that this kind of customizations only work in legacy Classic Checkout, but not in newly Checkout Block.
To show/hide checkout payments methods based on billing email and/or phone requires Ajax.
The following example will show "bacs" payment option (bank wire), only if the checkout billing email or billing phone matches with predefined ones:
// Embeded Javascript code (in checkout page only)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', 'enqueue_checkout_custom_js_script');
function enqueue_checkout_custom_js_script() {
    wc_enqueue_js( "    var email = $('[name=billing_email]').val(), 
        phone = $('[name=billing_phone]').val();
    
    $('form.checkout').on('change', '[name=billing_email],[name=billing_phone]', function() {
        const field = $(this).attr('name');
        if (field === 'billing_email') email = $(this).val();
        if (field === 'billing_phone') phone = $(this).val();

        if ( email.length > 0 && phone.length > 0 ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '" . admin_url('/admin-ajax.php') . "',
                data: {
                    'action' : 'checkout_billing_email_and_phone',
                    'email': field === 'billing_email' ? $(this).val() : email,
                    'phone': field === 'billing_phone' ? $(this).val() : phone,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            });
        }
    });" );
}

// PHP AJAX Receiver: Process ajax request
add_action('wp_ajax_checkout_billing_email_and_phone', 'update_session_billing_email_and_phone');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checkout_billing_email_and_phone', 'update_session_billing_email_and_phone');
function update_session_billing_email_and_phone() {
    if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) ) {
        $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
        $phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        WC()->customer->set_billing_email( $email );
        WC()->customer->set_billing_phone( $phone );
        WC()->customer->apply_changes();
        wp_die('Ajax: email or phone set');
    }
    wp_die();
}

// Filter available payment options dynamically in checkout page
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_available_payment_gateways');
function filter_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    // Below define in the corresponding arrays the allowed email and phones
    $allowed_phones = array('0145878545',' 0145878548', '0145874586');
    $allowed_emails = array('louis@gmail.com',' jack@gmail.com', 'lara@gmail.com');

    if ( ! ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_billing_phone(), $allowed_phones ) 
    || in_array( WC()->customer->get_billing_email(), $allowed_emails ) ) ) {
        unset($available_gateways['bacs']);
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
Related: Custom checkout field enable or disable payment methods in Woocommerce 3

This was what I implemented based on this answer you gave to someone with a similar question. But yeah, you deserve every credit for this answer also! Thank you very mush Loic, you're great!

Loic can you elaborate a little bit on the first if check within filter_available_payment_gateways function? I mean, I've seen (and used it) it numerous times like if ( ! is_checkout() ) or of course if ( is_checkout() ) depending on my goal. What about this if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) however? What is it checking? Does it check that we're in the actual checkout page and not in any of its endpoints shown here https://prnt.sc/jXw6hpri3IFm ?

Also I'm a bit confused about your condition's syntax in general... You negate ! the whole is_checkout() and the already negated is_wc_endpoint_url(). I mean, it works, but could there be any case that this would evaluate to true? Can you give me an example of a url that would evaluate to true, thus returning the $available_gateways array intact?

As payment methods are active in Checkout page and "Order pay" endpoint page, with is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() we target the checkout page exclusively. is_checkout() alone targets checkout page, Order received  and Order pay endpoint pages. As "order-received"  and "order-pay" are checkout endpoints, that why I use ! is_wc_endpoint_url()… So if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return $available_gateways; means that we exit from the function if it's not exclusively checkout page (returning the main function argument before our active code). Don't be confused

Now if you want the last function to be also active in "Order Pay" Checkout endpoint, you can replace if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) with if ( is_admin() )…
